# Can I run pie menu operator with two properties?

Tags: objects, parent, pie-menu

```
pie.operator("object.parent_set", text="Parent Object").type='OBJECT'
```

I can set the "object" type but I cannot set the "keep_transform" property to active.

```
pie.operator("object.parent_set", text="Parent Object", keep_transform=True).type='OBJECT'
```

I tried typing it like this but the option pie disappears from the menu.